# Print both strings and ints in a single loop

Tags: java

Sorry, if this is a vague question but I looked it up a lot and really stuck on my code here.

I want to make a loop which prints Strings on one line and Ints on the next, My code is:

```
public class StudentResult {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating Student Objects
        Student student1 = new Student("Bob", 45);
        Student student2 = new Student("John", 70);

        // Making Arrays for students and marks
        String[] names = {student1.getStudentName(), student2.getStudentName()};
        int[] marks = { student1.getStudentMarks(), student2.getStudentMarks() };

        // Using for loop to print both names and marks

        for (int mark : marks) {
            // THIS IS THE PART I AM STUCK WITH
            if (mark == student1.getStudentMarks()) System.out.println(names[0]);
            else if (mark == student2.getStudentMarks()) System.out.println(names[1]);

            System.out.println("The marks are " + mark);
             /* Output is :
                Bob
                The marks are 45
                John 
                The marks are 70
             */
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to edit the **If/Else** statement after the for loop, so that if I add another student object I would just have to edit my Arrays, and the loop works fine by itself.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking. To my guess, why don't you just **loop** the list of `Student`. Adding them into a `List<Student>` directly?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you are trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Got my answer, what I wanted was to replace those if/else statement with a simple statement that did the same thing but consistently, thank you for your time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an *indexed for loop* rather than a *for each* loop here (this is assuming both `names` and `marks` array of the same length.

```
for(int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i]);
    System.out.println("The marks are " + marks[i]);
}
```

Comment: That did it, thank you so much, such an easy fix but I got stuck so long, but learned a lot anyways.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you could try making an array of students:

```
Student student1 = new Student("Bob", 45);
Student student2 = new Student("John", 70);

Student[] students = { student1, student2 };

for (Student student : students) {
    System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
    System.out.println("The marks are " + getStudentMarks());
}
```

Comment: That's actually a great idea, thanks, I ll be sure to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using arrays, you could use a `List` such as `ArrayList`. For example

```
List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
    new Student("Bob", 45),
    new Student("John", 70)
);
```

The `ArrayList` returned by the `asList` method here is **immutable** meaning that even though it has `add` and `remove` methods (because it is a `List`), it is of fixed length, so if you need a mutable list, you need to do it a bit differently (like so)

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add(new Student("Bob", 45));
students.add(new Student("John", 70));
```

Here, you can `add` or `remove` elements, whereas in the first case, you would get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

You can then iterate the `List`

```
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s.getStudentName());
    System.out.println("The marks are " + s.getStudentMarks());
}
```

Alternatively, you can just use an array:

```
Student[] students = new Student[] { 
    new Student("Bob", 45),
    new Student("John", 70)
};

for (Student s : students) {
    // same as above
}
```

See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for the documentation.

Comment: I did not know this method, guess I'll have to look this up right now to understand it even better, thanks

Comment: @AneesUrRahman I updated my answer with more information. The `asList` method returns an immutable list so you may need to use something else depending on your needs. See the answer for more details.

Comment: @WilliamBurnham can I suggest that you move the stuff about immutability of the list underneath the array example (or just remove it entirely)? It's basically irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StudentResult
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    // Creating Student Objects
    Student student1 = new Student("Bob", 45);
    Student student2 = new Student("John", 70);

    Student[] students = { student1, student2 };

    // Using for loop to print both names and marks

    for (Student student : students)
    {

      System.out.println(student.getStudentName());
      System.out.println("The marks are " + student.getStudentMarks());

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could access both the arrays by iterating over them with the help of index.

```
int length = Math.min(names.length, marks.length);
for (int i=0; i< length; i++) {
  System.out.println(names[i] + "\n" + "The marks are " + marks[i]);
}
//If something is left over in any one of the arrays print them here.
```

Comment: This solves OP question, but his approach is probably bad. He should be printing an array of students instead multiple array of properties.

Comment: Yeah I agree @Rcordoval. But I was thinking like - he might got the arrays of names and marks (which is actually not constructed by him) - but they were the attributes of the `Student` object. So, I thought this could help him..

Comment: What do you mean? He is clearly constructing students and dump them into arrays. Anyway, is a valid answer. Cheers!

Comment: @Rcordoval : I meant someone could have constructed the array and pass it to him over the code flow - and for demo purpose he might have added it here.. I thought something like this..

Comment: This may not be the case :-) Thanks !

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll be sure to refine my code more and than ask a question, this was my second question, deleted the first one (Peer Pressure xD) and I m a beginner in java. Will be carefull next time